# Do bitwise rotations and increments modulo $2^n$ generate the symmetric group?

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups, binary

Let's say we have two operations we can perform on a binary number of length $n$:

1. Right-rotation, where the most significant bit is taken off and inserted in the one's place, pushing all other digits up.
2. Adding one to the number modulo $2^n$.

Do these two operations together generate the symmetric group? In other words, can every bijective function $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ be made through some composition of some number of those two operations? I don't see an easy way to prove it can't be done, because they don't distribute over each other, commute, or have an obvious rule about which bits can or can't impact other bits.

Comment: I can confirm empirically that it generates all permutations in the cases $n=1,2,3$. I don't see yet how to generalize this result, because the rotation image of some numbers changes whenever you increase the string length $n$.

Comment: Looks like through adding $1$ we get the ability to add $2^{n-1}$. This only affects the last bit. So what we can do is then toggle the last bit, then rotate, and do this for the whole length of the string to get any arbitrary permutation we desire.

Comment: @Merosity If I understand what you're saying, that allows you to perform a bitwise xor with a constant bitstring. Unfortunately I do not see how to get from there to an arbitrary permutation, because bitwise xors can only express $2^n$ permutations, when there are $2^n!$ permutations in existence.

Comment: @Merosity The question is whether you can use increments+rotations to form any *permutation* of bitstrings to bitstrings $2^n \rightarrow 2^n$.  Your reasoning shows that if you have two bitstrings $x$ and $y$ in mind, you can form a permutation that maps $x$ onto $y$. But it doesn't yet establish that you can simultaneously map all $2^n$ bitstrings in an arbitrary permutation onto $2^n$ bitstrings.

Comment: Yeah I worded that poorly, that's what I meant, which is why I left a comment and not an answer.